# Java : large integer numbers error

Tags: java, numbers, integer

I am trying to do the following math equation in Java:

```
(44334*(220*220))+ (81744*220) + 39416)
```

When I enter the same equation in WolframAlpha (or in Google) I get:

```
2163788696
```

In java I get negative number..

I have been struggling to find out why this is happening but with no luck.
I also tried saving the answer in a BigInteger, but then I get negative values because the digits are too large.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, what you are doing is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println(("result="+(44334*220*220)) + (81744*220 + 39416) );
// = "result=2145765600" + 18023096
// = "result=214576560018023096"
```

Parentheses are important! Here is your code fixed:

```
System.out.println("result=" + (44334*220*220+ 81744*220 + 39416) );
// = "result=2163788696"
```

**EDIT:**

Also beware of automatic `int` casting. Use `long`s because your result is bigger than `MAX_INT` (but smaller than `MAX_LONG` which is `9223372036854775807`).

```
(long)((long)44334*220*220 + (long)81744*220 + 39416)
```

Or put the suffix `L` after your numbers (so they're considered as `long`s).

Comment: OK, now I get negative result, how do I fix that?

Comment: I tried bigInteger with n lack,tried long as well with no luck at all

Comment: Try: `(long)((long)44334*220*220+ (long)81744*220 + 39416)`

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll add the comment in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: To deal with the integer wrap-around, use a `long`:

```
System.out.println("Result: " +
    (44334L * 220 * 220 + 81744 * 220 + 39416));  // 2163788696
```

The plus operator is left-associative (whether it's being used for string concatenation or addition), so if the entire arithmetic expression weren't parenthesized, it would be concatenating the results of the sub-expressions as individual strings from left to right.

The left operand determines whether + is used for string concatenation or addition. In this case, the first operand is a string, so the right side (`(44334*(220*220))`) is converted into a string as well. The result of the first + operator is a string and is used as the left side of another + string concatenation operation. the next operand (`(81744*220)`) gets converted to a string again.

You can put parentheses around the entire arithmetic expression to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the fact that the expression is evaluated from left to right. The first value is of type string, so the + operator then becomes the string concatenation operator instead of the mathmatical addition operator. The expressions `(44334*(220*220))` and `(81744*220)` are then evaluated and converted to strings leading to an incorrect result. If you surround the entire expression with parentheses, the result is calculated properly and you see the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `+` operator in Java is overloaded.  It can mean either string concatenation or numeric addition.  What is going on is that some of the `+` operations are being treated as string concatenations rather that numerical additions.

You need to either add a set of parentheses around the expression,

```
System.out.println("result="+((44334*(220*220))+ (81744*220) + 39416));
```

or use a temporary variable.

```
int res = (44334*(220*220))+ (81744*220) + 39416;
System.out.println("result="+res);
```

---

"The rules" that Java uses to determine the meaning of `+` are roughly as follows:

- If the type of the left **OR** right operand is String, then the `+` means string concatenation.
- If the types of both the left **AND** right operands are primitive numeric types or numeric wrapper types, then the `+` means a numeric addition.
- Otherwise this is a compilation error.

---

The other problem here is that `2163788696` is greater than the largest `int` value - `2147483647`.  So to get the right answer (without overflow), you need to tell Java to use `long` arithmetic; e.g.

```
System.out.println("result=" + ((44334L * (220 * 220)) + (81744 * 220) + 39416));
```

If you don't then `result` will be a negative number ... in this example.

You could also use `BigInteger`, but it is a bit cumbersome, and `long` will do just fine here.

Comment: You're gonna have a hard time since the result is bigger than `MAX_INT`. ;-)

Comment: yes, this is the problem now, I tried using BigInteger but still with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't just a `long` do it? But I'm not sure if you'd have to cast intermediary results as well.

Comment: Nop, long as far as I know is 9 digits, here is ten digits, (I tried that and I still got negative nmbers)

Comment: `MAX_LONG` is `(2^63)-1` which is `9223372036854775807`. Should be more than enough. Try casting intermediary results as well (or use just long variables).

Comment: thanks, you are right, it works just fine if I cast in the intermediate variables

Comment: That should be good. I don't remember what are the Java rules for intermediary computations. Will it cast back to `int` if one of the members isn't a long? If not, that will work great. BTW, some parentheses there are useless -> `(44334L * (220 * 220))` -> `44334L * 220 * 220`

Comment: Java will cast int to long. That's logical, casting long to int would cause lose of precision and Java won't let that happen (no matter if actual number 'fits' into int or not). Btw. Java will also upcast result of computation of shorts or byts to int.

Comment: "I don't remember what are the Java rules for intermediary computations. Will it cast back to int if one of the members isn't a long?" - Nope.  If either operand is long, the result is long.  In general the result type is the "wider" of the argument types ... but integer literals are treated differently.

Answer (score 1):

For the `BigInteger` version, try this, it will work correctly

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("44334").multiply(new BigInteger("220").multiply(new BigInteger("220")));
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("81744").multiply(new BigInteger("220"));
BigInteger c = new BigInteger("39416");
c = c.add(a).add(b);

System.out.println("resultVersA="+(44334*(220*220))+ (81744*220)  + 39416 );
System.out.println("resultVersB="+ c);
```

The result will be:

```
resultVersA=21457656001798368039416

resultVersB=2163788696
```

Comment: Great this worked just fine. Thanks. My error was that I did not create new BigInteger every time.

Comment: For convenience, because I am going to use this inside an equation with variables, not numbers, I used intermediate casting for that,(long)((long)44334*220*220+ (long)81744*220 + 39416) and it worked

Comment: Do you know how to cast the bigInt into an int? (at some point the result will get smaller(by using mode), and I will be able to store it into an int)

Comment: Yes, you could use the intValue method, but you will have a problem if the number is bigger then the max int.

Comment: Example: BigInteger c = new BigInteger("39416"); use c.intValue();

Comment: thanks, apparently, the long might be a little restrictive :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put an L after every number you write.

```
(44334L*(220L*220L))+ (81744L*220L) + 39416L
```

Comment: Thanks, but the numbers are just an example, I am going to use it with variables in an equation, which are quite big. So, i do not think it will work with the variable names

Comment: using long type (rather than int) parameters would do the trick then.